# Divide a java array like a numpy array

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to divide each element of a java float array by a constant, similarly to elementwise division possible with numPy arrays? Or is it necessary to iterate through the array with a loop and perform the division one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has nice utility functions:

```
Arrays.setAll(array, i -> array[i] / 2);
```